# Tomcat heap size increase in netbeans and how to find current heap size

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, heap-memory

I am using tomcat 7 on windows 7 SP1 with 3GB RAM. I am using some custom tag handlers to display data on a JSP page which constantly giving me heap size (out of memory) error.

I am using Netbeans 7.1 as development IDE, I tried to put -Xms256m -Xmx256m in VM option under project properties run option. I am not sure whether it is increasing heap size or not, **Is there any way to find out present heap size of tomcat?**

Or I need to do something else for increasing heap size? Because of no clue to find whether it is increasing heap size or not, I am not able to debug where the problem is, with low heap size or something with my code.

Comment: Have you tried using jconsole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to get some information about running VMs.

Comment: thanks for this. Quite helpful software, tells almost everything required in real time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String heapMemUsage() 
{
    long used = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed();
    long max = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax();
    return ""+used+" of "+max+" ("+ used/(double)max*100.0 + "%)";
}
```

Comment: Neat method to get quick information about memory consumption inside the running program itself.

Comment: If you want to see from the outside, try using probe: http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/

Comment: @Woody: thanks, its quite helpful to know memory consumption from the program itself